# Is different date format comparison works in Informatica?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, date-comparison

Suppose my source data is coming in the format of 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' and i want to compare with a date format of 'MM/DD/YYYY' will it work or do i need to change the format of and make both the field in same format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert to respective format and then compare

If your date column from the source is string, you have to convert it to date format and then to respective format, using below function,

```
Port1(Variable port) -  Date_V : TO_DATE(date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
Port2(Output port) -  Date_O : TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Date_V, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

If your date format from the source is already in date format, you just have convert to the respective format,

```
   TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(NEWFIELD1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: I think this is not the case, as when converting the source string field to date it will automatically change the field to the date format define in the session properties and thus in this way for any date comparison the field only needs to be in date type both the format will be automatically changed to the format defined in session properties. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: No, your understanding is wrong. Since Jim is mentioning format in to_date() function, informatica wont do anything but will convert to  a date. Now, you can easily compare. See, in your case data type and format should be same to compare. So, Jim converted both to date to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Well... There's no such thing as different date format ;)

What you're actually talking here about, is strings. Once you convert your `strings` to `date`, you're free to compare them. A `date` is a kind of a number, in fact.